# Docker - Share local storage between services

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm building a multi-container App. Here is the overall view of the working directory:

```
MABSED/
|_ docker-compose.yml
|_ ...
|_ streamer/
|  |_ Dockerfile
|  |_ startStreaming.py
|  |_ credentials.py
|_ orchestrator/
   |_ Dockerfile
   |_ requirements.txt
   |_ tasks.py
   |_ my_sched.py
   |_ data/
   |  |_ streaming/
   |  |_ preprocessed/
   |  |_ results/
   |_ detector/
   |_ filter/
   |_ lemmatizer/
```

My App has 4 different services: an ElastisSearch container, a dashboard, a Streamer which captures tweets from Twitter and an Orchestrator which performs a task and saves the results in ElasticSearch.

This question involves just two of the services, the Streamer and the Orchestrator. As I have said I want this two components to share the data, what applied to my App means that I want the Orchestrator to be able to access the tweets captured by the Streamer. Moreover, I want this data to be stored on my computer local directory `MABSED/orchestrator/data/` and not only in the container, in case I need to access that information once I have stopped the process.

In other words, I need that when I do `docker-compose up` this two containers get the data stored in `MABSED/orchestrator/data/` and add the corresponding files, so that when Streamer adds a new file to `MABSED/orchestrator/data/streaming/` Orchestrator can notice this change and add a new file to `MABSED/orchestrator/data/results/`.

Also `startStreaming.py` which is the script which Streamer service run saves the data to this relative path `output_directory = '../orchestrator/data/streaming'`, which works fine on local but I don't know if it will on the Docker container.

By this moment, my `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
  dashboard:
    build: demo-dashboard/
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - ES_ENDPOINT_EXTERNAL=http://localhost:9200
      - http.cors.enabled=true
      - http.cors.allow-origin=ES_ENDPOINT_EXTERNAL
      - http.cors.allow-headers=Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With
      - http.cors.allow-credentials=true
    volumes:
     - ./demo-dashboard:/usr/src/app
    networks:
      - dashboard-network

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.7.0
    environment:
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - http.cors.enabled=true
      - http.cors.allow-origin=http://localhost:8080
      - http.cors.allow-headers=Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With
      - http.cors.allow-credentials=true
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    mem_limit: 1g
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - dashboard-network
    ports:
      - 9200:9200

  orchestrator:
    image: orchestrator-mabsed
    build: orchestrator/
    environment:
      ES_HOST: 'elasticsearch'
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./orchestrator/data/:/usr/src/app/orchestrator/data

  streamer:
    image: streamer-mabsed
    build: streamer/
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./orchestrator/data/:/usr/src/orchestrator/data

volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local

networks:
  dashboard-network:
    driver: bridge
```

I think I would need to create a volume in order to achieve this, but I'm relatively new to Docker and I don't know how to manage this.

Here are my **Streamer Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN pip3 install --user tweepy

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
COPY startStreaming.py /usr/src/app/
COPY credentials.py /usr/src/app/

CMD python startStreaming.py
```

and my **Orchestrator Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3.6

COPY . /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
RUN pip3 install --user -r requirements.txt

CMD python my_sched.py
```

Comment: Instead of trying to use the filesystem, can you use some external data store; for example, storing the data principally in Elasticsearch?  That avoids this problem, makes it easier to scale the services, and works better in clustered environments.

Answer (score 1):

You can share the same local directory with your services.
Just make sure that your code refers to the directory accordingly (shared path).
In this case, **/usr/src/app/orchestrator/data**

Sample:-

```
orchestrator:
image: orchestrator-mabsed
build: orchestrator/
environment:
  ES_HOST: 'elasticsearch'
tty: true
volumes:
  - MABSED/orchestrator/data/:/usr/src/app/orchestrator/data

streamer:
 image: streamer-mabsed
 build: streamer/
 tty: true
 volumes:
  - MABSED/orchestrator/data/:/usr/src/app/orchestrator/data
```

Comment: I edited the `docker-compose.yml` as can be seen in the question. Now the Streamer works, files are generated in my local repository althought navigating through the container the directory /usr/src/orchestrator/ doesn't exists I don't know why. However Orchestrator service doesn't realize that new files has been created as it still ask for an already existing file. Any idea what should I need to add?

Comment: In streamer app also, can you check the path of the shared directory? Currently it is - ./orchestrator/data/:/usr/src/orchestrator/data shouldn't it be - ./orchestrator/data/:/usr/src/app/orchestrator/data

Comment: I mapped the host directory in that path because my Streamer script saves files locally in `../orchestrator/data/streaming/` and I wanted it to have coherence locally and in the container. Should the destiny path be the same in both containers or it only matters the source path of the volume? @VineetPalan